# How to make Chai print assertion's parameter name instead of it's value

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, chai

I use Mocha with Chai for testing. Mocha shows the whole test's code when you expand test case with left mouse click in browser, but when any of Chai's assertions fail, I get something like:

**Expected undefined to exist**

Such case is pretty hard to find if textual description wasn't originally given to assertion as it's second argument.
Is there a way to get something like

**Expected foo.bar to exist**

P.S. I use webpack, so assertion's line number means nothing (it's possible to find through file generated by webpack, but it's hard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai has no functionality that you can just turn on to get the kind of report you are hoping for. In many cases I find the stock messages produced by Chai to not be accurate enough to quickly find what the problem is, so I set custom messages. For instance:

```
it("should test promise throwing error", () => {
    const foo;
    expect(foo, "foo should exist").to.exist;
});
```

If the redundancy of `expect(...).to.exist` and `"... should exist"` annoys you, you can shorten the message to a string that is descriptive enough for your needs: `expect(foo, "foo").to.exist`. It does not completely eliminate the manual work but it reduces it.

For an automatic solution, you'd have to write a wrapper for `expect` that is able to extract the name of the parameters that are passed to it. That's not a trivial task.

Comment: Thank you for answer. As I understand, the answer is: there is now way to do it using Chai out of the box. What is a bit weird since Mocha does the it for every test case, printing it's body.

Comment: You understood correctly. Printing the source of a function is built into the JavaScript standard: if `fn` is a function you can just do `fn.toString()` to get the source (and that's exactly what Mocha does: `this.body = (fn || '').toString();`). Finding what JavaScript expressions were used when a function was called is an entirely different kettle of fish. You could use something like [`esprima`](http://esprima.org/) but while esprima can help a lot, there's still a lot of work to be done with the AST that esprima produces in order to find the information you'd want.